# matching literals in match in racket

Tags: racket

How can I match literals in racket? This doesn't seem to work:

```
(define (foo e)
  (match e
    [(list + e1 e2)  "+"]
    [(list - e1 e2)  "-"]))
```

It returns "+" for both of `(foo '(+ 1 2))` and `(foo '(- 1 2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the patterns `(list '+ e1 e2)` and `(list '- e1 e2)` (with the `'`s!), since otherwise `+` and `-` are treated as ordinary identifiers and match anything, just like `e1` and `e2` do.